# Not able to get formatted date from database sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with timestamp column and the values stored in timestamp column are like

20180608T002304.507Z , 20180608T001745.821Z, 20180608T001628.170Z, 20180608T001336.516Z

I would like to get timestamp in "**YYYY-MM-dd**" formate.

Used strftime() function , but no use

when I query **strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', timestamp)** getting **null**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not one of the [supported time string formats](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Change the values so that they contain the appropriate punctuation:

```
sqlite> SELECT date('20180608T002304.507Z');

sqlite> SELECT date('2018-06-08T00:23:04.507Z');
2018-06-08
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `strftime` along with all the SQLite date functions require specific formats as listed below.  20180608T002304.507Z is not one of the formats, hence the null.

- **Note** the following is based upon your query using *strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', timestamp)* as opposed to *I would like to get timestamp in "YYYY-MM-dd" formate.*

You have two options.

#### 1. You could utilise the **`substr`** function e.g.

:-

```
substr(mytimestamp,1,4)||'-'||
substr(mytimestamp,5,2)||'-'||
substr(mytimestamp,7,2)||' ' ||
substr(mytimestamp,10,2)||':'||
substr(mytimestamp,12,2)
```

- where mytimestamp is the column name

As an example, the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (mytimestamp);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('20180608T002304.507Z'),('20180608T001745.821Z'),('20180608T001628.170Z'),('20180608T001336.516Z');
SELECT 
    substr(mytimestamp,1,4)||'-'||
    substr(mytimestamp,5,2)||'-'||
    substr(mytimestamp,7,2)||' ' ||
    substr(mytimestamp,10,2)||':'||
    substr(mytimestamp,12,2)
FROM mytable;
```

results in :-

[image]

#### 2. Alter the source data to match one of the acceptable/recognised formats.

This could be done using something based upon :-

```
UPDATE mytable SET mytimestamp = 
    substr(mytimestamp,1,4)||'-'|| -- Year
    substr(mytimestamp,5,2)||'-'|| -- Month
    substr(mytimestamp,7,2)|| -- Day
    substr(mytimestamp,9,1)||      -- T (or space)
    substr(mytimestamp,10,2)||':'||
    substr(mytimestamp,12,2)||':'||
    substr(mytimestamp,14)
    ;
```

- This based upon the table that was created above.

After running the update then using :-

```
SELECT  strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', mytimestamp) FROM mytable;
```

results in :-

[image]

> **Time Strings** A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> 1. YYYY-MM-DD
> 2. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> 3. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> 4. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> 5. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> 6. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> 7. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> 8. HH:MM
> 9. HH:MM:SS
> 10. HH:MM:SS.SSS
> 11. now
> 12. DDDDDDDDDD
>
> In formats 5 through 7, the "T" is a literal character separating the
> date and the time, as required by ISO-8601. Formats 8 through 10 that
> specify only a time assume a date of 2000-01-01. Format 11, the string
> 'now', is converted into the current date and time as obtained from
> the xCurrentTime method of the sqlite3_vfs object in use. The 'now'
> argument to date and time functions always returns exactly the same
> value for multiple invocations within the same sqlite3_step() call.
> Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) is used. Format 12 is the Julian day
> number expressed as a floating point value.
>
> Formats 2 through 10 may be optionally followed by a timezone
> indicator of the form "[+-]HH:MM" or just "Z". The date and time
> functions use UTC or "zulu" time internally, and so the "Z" suffix is
> a no-op. Any non-zero "HH:MM" suffix is subtracted from the indicated
> date and time in order to compute zulu time. For example, all of the
> following time strings are equivalent:
>
> - 2013-10-07 08:23:19.120
> - 2013-10-07T08:23:19.120Z
> - 2013-10-07 04:23:19.120-04:00
> - 2456572.84952685
>
> In formats 4, 7, and 10, the fractional seconds value SS.SSS can have
> one or more digits following the decimal point. Exactly three digits
> are shown in the examples because only the first three digits are
> significant to the result, but the input string can have fewer or more
> than three digits and the date/time functions will still operate
> correctly. Similarly, format 12 is shown with 10 significant digits,
> but the date/time functions will really accept as many or as few
> digits as are necessary to represent the Julian day number.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)